# Can't add JPanel to BorderLayout.CENTER

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am just Starting out with JAVA.
I have say a JPanel x, a JPanel y and a BorderLayout JPanel z.
When I try to change the contents of the center of z from default x t y, it works but it doesn't go back to x. I AM calling revalidate() after each. Help please.
The class below is where the problem is.

**Main Class Below**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unused" })
public class Manager extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Manager frame = new Manager();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Manager() {
        setTitle("Popper");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();
        height = height/5.1;
        setSize((int)width, (int)height);
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(14,99,165));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D:/popper26.png");
        setIconImage(image.getImage());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        calcu cal = new calcu();
        curr nup = new curr();
        stopc newst = new stopc();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout x =new BorderLayout(0,0);
        mainpanel.setLayout(x);
        mainpanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel madeby = new JLabel("Project By Anant Bhasin");
        madeby.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        mainpanel.add(madeby, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel logo = new JPanel();
        logo.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        JLabel jk = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:/popper2.png"));
        logo.add(jk, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        logo.setBackground(Color.decode("#1abc9c"));
        mainpanel.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainpanel.add(cal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(mainpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel newj = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout bxl = new BoxLayout(newj, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        newj.setLayout(bxl);
        newj.setBackground(new Color(58,115,144));
        contentPane.add(newj, BorderLayout.WEST);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        JButton calc = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/calc.png"));
        newj.add(calc);
        calc.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        calc.setFocusPainted(false);
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                mainpanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cal);
                mainpanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        JButton currb = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/curr.png"));
        currb.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        newj.add(currb);
        currb.setFocusPainted(false);
        currb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                mainpanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, nup);
                mainpanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        JButton stop = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/stop.png"));
        stop.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        newj.add(stop);
        stop.setFocusPainted(false);
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                mainpanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, newst);
                mainpanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        JButton timer = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/timer.png"));
        timer.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        newj.add(timer);
        timer.setFocusPainted(false);
        JButton memo = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:/memo.png"));
        memo.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        newj.add(memo);
        memo.setFocusPainted(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: Please add some code to better explain your question

Comment: Divide your code into modules (methods), don't put everything in constructor, now it is big blob.

Comment: Added code. After pressing JButton currb or stop once or even before that JButton calc doesn't do anything.

Comment: Gave you a 1+ up-vote for improving the question. Your answer is as per Rob Camick's post (1+ to his answer as well). You'd do well to heed his advice, I know that I do.

Comment: @Yoda, it isn't a commercial project or even one that is going to be published. This was why I didn't put the code in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BorderLayout` is not designed to display multiple components with the same constraint because of the way ZOrder painting works in Swing.

If you need the ability to swap panels, then you should be using a `CardLayout`.

A `CardLayout` lets you specify the name of the panel that you want to display. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

You set up the layout with code like:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel( new CardLayout() );
main.add(panelx, "X");
main.add(panely, "Y");
```

Then to swap a panel you use code like:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(main.getLayout());
cl.show(main, "X");
```

Comment: Thanks for that. CardLayout seems interesting but isn't there a way to fix it without editing the layout. I'd surely keep the CardLayout in mind next time but a quick fix is what I'm looking for right now.

Comment: As I said only one component can be displayed, so you need to remove the old panel and then add the new panel. Why do you think using a CardLayout is so difficult? From what I see in your code you have 3 panels sharing the CENTER. So how do you know which panel to remove before adding the new one? CardLayout simplifies the process because you don't care what panel is currently displayed. You just specify the panel you want to display which is always much simpler logic. Use CardLayout will take a couple of minutes to change your code.